# Meteor Mongo.Cursor#map doesn't have the desired effect

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a client side local collection named `Cart` which holds product objects. What I want to do is return to the template the sum of all the products and quantities in the collection. I do this as follows:

```
Template.layout.helpers({

  cartTotal: () => {
    if( !Cart.findOne({}) ) {
      return 0;
    }
    else {
      let productsCursor = Cart.find({});
      let totalPrice = 0;

      productsCursor.map((product) => {
        let subtotal = product.qty*product.price;
        totalPrice =+ subtotal;
        console.log(totalPrice);
      });

      return totalPrice.toFixed(2);
    }
  }
});
```

Everything sums nicely when I'm adding the same product to the collection (increasing the `product.qty` by 1), but when I add another object to the `Cart` collection, it starts to sum only the quantities and price in this object.

If I inspect the Collection on the browser console, all the objects are there, but the result of the `cartTotal` method is not returning the correct value.

I've already tried to use the `Mongo.Cursor#forEach()` method, but the result is the same. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do??? What is wrong???

Answer (score 0):

This may be something to do with reactivity. Try directly mapping the cursor as opposed to saving it as a variable as shown below:

```
Template.layout.helpers({

  cartTotal: () => {
    if( !Cart.findOne({}) ) {
      return 0;
    }
    else {

      let totalPrice = 0;

      Cart.find({}).map((product) => {
        let subtotal = product.qty*product.price;
        totalPrice =+ subtotal;
        console.log(totalPrice);
      });

      return totalPrice.toFixed(2);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... :( But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if this is a bug on minimongo or on babel, but substituting `totalPrice =+ subtotal;` for `totalPrice = totalPrice + subtotal;` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Both your code and one of the answer's code contains `=+`.

Not a surprise, that you get the total price for only one product, because you don't adjust the price, but rewrite it in every iteration:

```
// let total price be the subtotal with positive sign
totalPrice = +subtotal;
```

You definitely mean `+=`, which is not the same.

I encourage you trying functional approach:

```
Template.layout.helpers({
  cartTotal() {
    Cart.find()
    .map(product => product.qty * product.price)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0)
    .toFixed(2);
  }
});
```